# Passing variable as argument from 1 python script to another in Windows 7 environment

Tags: python, arguments, subprocess

I am learning python and ran into a bit of an issue that I haven't been able to figure out how to do. To keep it simple, lets say I have 2 scripts: Main and CalledScript. I want Main to open an executable and get its pid, assign that to a variable and then open CalledScript.py as a subprocess and pass that variable to it as an argument. While I know that in most cases using import would be a better option, in my case I have to run it as a subprocess due to other parts of my project. Anyhow, I keep getting an error when I do this. It only happens when I try to send the pid. If I were to assign the variable "thePid" below with just some random number like "555" it would work just fine. CalledScript would receive it, print it to the screen, and all is well. But trying to assign it cproc.pid and send it doesn't go over well.

Without further delay, here is a simple sample code:

**Main.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
import subprocess
import os

cproc = Popen("C:\Test\Test.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

thePid = cproc.pid

theproc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\CalledScript.py', thePid], shell=True)
```

**CalledScript.py**

```
import sys

print "thePid is: %r" % sys.argv[1]
```

The error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    theproc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\CalledScript.py
', cproc.pid], shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 852, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 587, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Any help would be outstanding! Sorry for the likely very obvious question. I searched around on google but didn't have much luck finding an answer! I just started messing with python the other day so I'm still learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try passing the pid as string, not as int:

```
theproc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\CalledScript.py', str(thePid)])
```

And using `shell=True` makes no sense if you're passing the arguments as a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

For me using this works:

```
    theproc = subprocess.Popen("./CalledScript.py " + str(thePid),shell=True)
```

But using this does not work:

```
    theproc = subprocess.Popen(['./CalledScript.py', str(thePid)], shell=True)
```

ubuntu, python 2.7.2+